# Redirecting Links From Submitted HTML Form Value With Flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a search bar on my Flask powered website which works well when the user clicks the search button (I am using a JS code with a `POST` request). However it doesn't work when the user sends the form with an 'enter' click. In those cases the browser loads a link like this `/?finder=searchedword`.

The `finder` is the value of the `name` attribute of the html code used for the form. In order to solve the problem, I have tried to setup a redirect that always redirects to the proper link that should be loaded, but unfortunately using this solution doesn't work. It just simply redirects to the main page `"/"`.

This is how I manage the redirect:

```
@app.route("/?finder=<tag>")
def search(tag):
    t = tag.replace(' ', '-')
    return redirect("/result/%s/" % (t,), code=301)
```

My question is what would be the proper technique to handle this type of redirection? This kind of redirection always works for me and I am using it in several apps, therefore I have no idea what is the weak part of the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Past the question mark is not actually part of the route but rather is arguments to the page.  So Flask is just matching the url "/".

Try something like this:

```
@app.route("/")
def search():
    if "finder" in request.args:
        t = request.args["finder"].replace(" ", "-")
        return redirect("/result/%s/" % (t,), code=301)
```